# Wrap of a Map inside a ListViewBuilder (hard)

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

So I have this (complicated) map

```
Map collection = { "CompanyA", {"Departement1",{EmployeeA, EmployeeB, EmployeeC}, {Departement2,{EmployeeD} }, "CompanyB", {"Departement3",{EmployeeE, EmployeeF, EmployeeG}, {"Departement4",{EmployeeH} }
```

Company, Departement are String and Employee are object.

I'm trying to display them like this
"Company"
"Departement"
Employee-Employee-Employee-
Employee-Employee

So basically a list for the titles then a wrap for the employees.

```
class CompaniesSection extends StatelessWidget {
  Map collection;
  CompaniesSection({required this.collection, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List companiesNames = collection.keys.toList();
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: collection.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 30,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(170, 200, 21, 81),
                  child: Text(
                    companiesNames[index],
                    style: GoogleFonts.dmSerifDisplay(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Wrap(
                  children: [
                    for (var i in collection[titles[index]]) 

                    
                  ],
                )
              ]));
        });
  }
```

But now I'm stuck I don't know how to display the departements names then the wrap of Employees